# List available DB providers

Tags: .net, connection-string

I have some problems with building connection strings. I used to generate "Provider=SQLOLEDB" or "Provider=SQLNCLI". Now I see that some users have SQLNCLI10 while SQLNCLI is missing. Is it possible to enumerate available providers so I could pick a valid one?

System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses() lists .NET data providers but I still don't know which connection string parameters are valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` (either directly or indirectly) then there is no need to specify a Provider element in the connection string.  I imagine this value is simply ignored if provided.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) for the comprehensive list of all supported elements in `SqlConnection` connection strings.

However, if you're using OleDb, this does what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator.aspx

For example:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader dataReader = OleDbEnumerator.GetRootEnumerator())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", dataReader[0], dataReader[2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thaks, this OleDbEnumerator does just what I want.

Answer (score -1):

For more details on connection string, see [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: This is not an answer to this question